# How do I extract only public properties from an object to a structure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, object, struct

If I have the following class:

```
classdef foo
    properties
        bar1
        bar2
        bar3
    end
    properties(Access = private)
        bar4
        bar5
    end
end
```

and do the following:

```
myObj = foo();
test = struct(myObj);
```

`test` would have all 5 properties of `foo` as fields, including the private properties:

```
test = 

        bar1: NaN
        bar2: NaN
        bar3: NaN
        bar4: NaN
        bar5: NaN
```

I'm hoping to create a structure that has just the public properties of `myObj` as fields:

```
test = 

        bar1: NaN
        bar2: NaN
        bar3: NaN
```

How do I extract a structure of just the public properties from an object?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a class' public properties by using `properties`, from there it would not be too hard to just copy the fields, e.g.:

```
myObj = foo();
props = properties(myObj); % or properties('foo') or fieldnames(myObj)
myStruct = cell2struct(cellfun(@(prop) myObj.(prop), props, 'UniformOutput', false), props, 1);
```

or create the struct and remove the private fields:

```
myObj = foo();
myStruct = struct(myObj);
myStruct = rmfield(myStruct, setdiff(fieldnames(myStruct), properties(myObj)));
```

Answer (score 2):

For a more general solution (i.e. if you wanted to find properties with different set and get visibilities), you could use either the `?` operator, or the `metaclass` function.  This will return an object which describes all the information about your class.

```
myDefinition = ?foo
myProperties = myDefinition.PropertyList
isPublic = strcmp({myProperties.SetAccess}, 'public') & strcmp({myProperties.GetAccess}, 'public')
myPublicProperties = myProperties(isPublic)
myPublicPropertyNames = {myPublicProperties.Name}
```

Results in:

```
myPublicPropertyNames = 

    'bar1'    'bar2'    'bar3'
```

Now that you know which of your properties are public, you can convert this information into any form you like (including a structure which is covered by @erikced's answer).